# Resolution of two frequencies

Tags: optics, frequency

If I am trying to resolve two features in frequency space, with central frequencies A and B and a 'spread' (standard deviation, FWHM etc.) of $\sigma_A$ and $\sigma_B$ what is the spectral separation $\Delta \omega$ needed to resolve these features?

I'm just looking for a simple formula that is commonly used. I'm sure it has something to do with the Rayleigh criterion, but I can't find anything definitive to do with frequency space, just angular and spatial resolution.

[image]

To be specific, I have derived Landau levels for a system and I have typical variances in related quantities which give me an idea of how broad these levels will be, so I want to know if they will be resolvable in reality.

Comment: Resolution is subjective, in general. Take a look: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/raylei.html In imaging we usually use FWHM as resolution. But resolution should take into account signal-to-noise ratio, as higher noise makes harder to resolve peaks. Also, forget that it is frequency space, treat your data as just some signal

Comment: Sure, I'd be happy to use FWHM, and I understand the subjectivity but there must be a convention that I can implement. My work is theory so I'm not concerned in the details I just want to justify my results and convince others the levels are in principle resolvable. Thank you for the link but this also is talking about angular resolution and I don't see how I can relate it to the question?

Comment: It doesn't matter if its an angular resolution or whatever. As aaaaaa pointed out, forget that it is frequency space. Just look at you picture. Now it is maybe interesting to know what is the narrowest feature you can obtain with your measurement device, and if the distance AB is smaller than this you can say that your two peaks will be undistinguishable. The Rayleigh criterion commes from the diffraction limit, so you must know your measurement device limits

Comment: Ok I see. In this case for my purposes I'm considering two identical distributions. If I approximate them as normal distributions then I calculated it means I need a frequency separation of $\Delta\omega > 2\sqrt{\ln (4)}\sigma$

Comment: I still was hoping to have a source for this but I guess that'll do.

Comment: The only objective criterion you can have is linked to the resolution of your device. Otherwise it's a little arbitrary (like the Rayleigh criterion)

Comment: It's not as "subjective" as it is portrayed in many old style textbooks, but the mathematical problem to make it objective is non-trivial, as are the numerical implementations to resolve within classical Gaussian limits. aaaaaa's first comment is the best one, you need to know the line profiles and the noise spectra and then you can reconstruct even deeply overlapping lines, which is the standard signal processing technique for such signals these days. Your phone and your wireless router are doing just that all day long.